# Terminal voltage derivation

Tags: electromagnetism, voltage, batteries

How can I prove the following?

$\ V_{ab}=\mathcal E-\ Ir$.

Here $\ V_{ab} $  is terminal voltage.

Comment: And $r$ is the internal resistance?

Comment: @John Rennie Yeah.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing to prove. It's a definition.

We observe that as we draw current from a battery, its terminal voltage drops. Using the Taylor series, we know that over limited range of currents, we can model this effect with a linear model:

$$V = V_0 + I\frac{dV}{dI}$$

We then define $r=-\frac{dV}{dI}$, and identify that the terminal voltage with no load current is the battery's emf, and we have your model:

$$V = {\mathcal E} - rI.$$

Comment: There is nothing to prove because it is a physical law valid for electrochemical cell discovered by Georg Ohm, not because it's a definition.

Comment: @JánLalinský, Ohm's Law (as discovered by Ohm) applies to metallic conductors. If he also discovered this relationship for electrochemical cells, could you share the reference?

Comment: He discovered it for a circuit driven by thermocouple, but I think he realized the same for voltaic cell since he made lots of experiments with it as well. See G. Ohm, *Bestimmung des Gesetzes, nach welchem Metalle die Contakt elektricitat leiten, nebst einem Entwurfe zu einer Theorie des Voltaischen Apparates und des Schweiggerschen Multiplicators*, J. Chemie Physik, vol. 46, pp. 137-166, 1826. English translation https://www.jstor.org/stable/43429004 , formula for X on p. 69.

Comment: See also account of Ohm's work here https://www.researchgate.net/publication/3052303_Georg_Simon_Ohm_and_Ohm's_Law , p. 158, formula (6).